# content of the tabs are displaying incorrectly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a simple tab. I cant figure out what am I doing wrong here. I need some help in debugging this. Here is my JS. The contents dont show up correctly.

```
jQuery('.containers .tabs li:first-child a').addClass('active');
jQuery('.containers').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.container:first').addClass('active');
});
var forClick = jQuery('.containers .tabs li a');
jQuery(forClick).click(function () {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr('class');
    var parent = jQuery(this).closest('.containers');
    parent.find('.active').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    parent.find('.' + title + 'Content').addClass('active');
});

if (jQuery(forClick).is(':empty')) {
    jQuery('.containers').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/4sEMw/2/

Note: No plugins can be used such as JQuery UI etc.

Comment: what is your desired effect?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [jQuery UI's Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

- `var title = jQuery(this).attr('class');` followed by `parent.find('.' + title + 'Content').addClass('active');`

When the button is active, the class attribute ends up being `"tab1 active"`, which when you attempt to use it as a selector results in `".tab1 activeContent"`

To address that, you could put something like `if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) return;` in your click event.

- `<div class="container tab1Content" id="product2_nw">`

You assigned the wrong `tabContent` class to your second container.

All that being said: **Why make your own?**
I'd recommend using an existing tab plugin like [jQuery UI's](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Comment: @Daniel--I actually found the issue and never came back and checked the post. Apologies. This exactly was the problem